Setup Laravel Sanctum in a Laravel and Nuxt application
I have an application with Laravel 8 as a backend and Nuxt 3 as a frontend. On my MAMP server it works fine with localhost:3000 for the frontend and localhost:8000 for the backend.
In production I have a droplet with Ubuntu in Digital Ocean and two domains connected via Cloudflare to the droplet (one for the frontend and one for the backend).
My Laravel .env configuration is:
...
APP_URL=http://api-alluminio.adokstudio.it      
FRONTEND_URL=http://alluminio.adokstudio.it

SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug
...

And my config/cors.php is:
'paths' => [
        '*',
        'api/*', 
        '/login',
        '/register',
        '/logout',
        '/sanctum/csrf-cookie',
    ],

My /etc/nginx/sites-available:
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name api-alluminio.adokstudio.it www.api-alluminio.adokstudio.it;

    root /var/www/md-alluminio-api/public;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}

When I try to do a Get call to /sanctum/csrf-cookie in Postman I don't get anything and when I try to login to alluminio.adokstudio.it/login I get a 419 error.
I tried to change the SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost to SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost but it doesn't work, also I tried to reinstall composer.
